# Выдернуть URL из строки

Tags: php

Как можно из строки вытащить URL? 
parse_url - теряется в строках, ему тока сам url подавай. 
Есть ли еще что, что мне помогло б.

Comment: Используйте регулярные выражения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если из строки c HTML разметкой, попробуйте след. код:

```
function linkExtract($html) {
    $a = array();
    if (preg_match_all(
        '/<a\s+.*?href=[\"\']?([^\"\' >]*)[\"\']?[^>]*>(.*?)<\a>/i',
        $html,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        foreach($matches as $match) {
            array_push($a,array($match[1],$match[2]));
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
```